# APACHE Reescrita de URL do subdomínio de um Servidor (A) para um subdiretório de um Servidor (B)

Tags: linux, apache

Minha aplicação está no servidor (A)
Acessível através da URL: nome.dominio.com.br

Possuo um outro servidor (B)
Acessível através da URL: www.dominio.com.br

Preciso acessar, essa url do servidor (B) desta forma
ULR: www.dominio.com.br/nome

E preciso que ela aponte para nome.dominio.com.br

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso via Apache?

Answer (score 1):

Eu não estou com o ambiente preparado para fazer o teste agora. Mas encontrei essa informação no SO em Inglês:

Apache mod_proxy

> `ProxyPass /mirror/foo/ http://backend.example.com/`

Parece ser o que você está procurando. Por favor responda a esta mensagem informando se funcionou. Caso não seja o que está procurando, eu removerei essa mensagem.

Comment: Nem sempre o serviço de hospedagem tem mod_proxy instalado, tem que verificar isso antes.